# Get text from txt file on the internet

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a uwp and i need to get text from a txt file saved on the internet to string I have a problem with download the file and get the text to string

Here's my code:

```
            var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"http://yourUrl");
        using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var content = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
        {
            var strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: `webRequest.GetResponse()` couldn't find

Comment: @L.B I have a problem with the secound line on my code `webRequest.GetResponse`

Comment: @L.B nothing happened still have the same error :/

Comment: This should work, Can you tell us what is the error you're getting ?.. Try Also to add UserAgent header and see if the server requires some cookies or headers to view the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help I've used HttpClient and it's worked for me I have post the answer for another one who have the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find an answer to my question

I've to download the txt file to my local storage and after that i read them from my local

Here's the code that i used to download the file to my local folder

```
            var uriBing = new Uri(@"https://your/abc.txt");
        StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("status.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var cli = new HttpClient();
        Byte[] bytes = await cli.GetByteArrayAsync(uriBing);
        IBuffer buffer = bytes.AsBuffer(); await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(sampleFile, buffer);
```

Thanks for helping hope this will help anyone look for something like this

Answer (score 3):

```
var url = "http://example.com/abc.txt";
var textFromFile = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: There's no `webclient` on uwp :/

Comment: no i'm using my url but i write "yourUrl" in the post not more not less but there's no webclient in uwp !

Comment: dear i answered you .i edited my answer read it again. i dont know more.i am sorry louay. :(