# How to read data from a text on the internet UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a text file and I want to save the text to a string to use it later in the app but I couldn't find a way to do that !
here's my shot :

```
    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.sdd.com/s.txt");
    using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
    using (var content = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
    {
        var strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

but this code not work at all !

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer here [How to get txt on the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062032/get-text-from-txt-file-on-the-internet)

after you download the file to your local storage you can read it simply

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download a text file, there is an even simpler way, avoiding a file altogether, using `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` method:

```
var textFileUri = new Uri(@"http://www.sdd.com/s.txt");
var client = new HttpClient();
var fileContents = await client.GetStringAsync( textFileUri );
```

Comment: thanks I'm already find my answer :)